# Search and replace value in-between quotes

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a file on OSX that I would like to cat out and replace all instances in-between double quotes with the same value, but make it color. This value between the quotes is not constant. I'm stuck.

example:

```
Before:
username "test1" blah "fasdf fsaf"
username "test2" blah "more blah"

After:
username "<blue>test1</blue>" blah "<blue>fasdf fsaf</blue>"
username "<blue>test2</blue>" blah "<blue>more blah</blue>"
```

Comment: This works perfectly, except it doesn't output the entire file. Whereas grep value|$ works on linux, it doesn't seem to work on OSX

Comment: *what* works perfectly?

Comment: Sorry, someone suggested grep --color, but then removed their comment

Comment: ah.  you could do: grep -C`wc -l <file` --color -e '"[^"]*"' file
but that would color the "'s too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -wpe's!"([^"]*)"!"<blue>$1</blue>"!g' filename
```

Comment: This works, thank you! would you mind elaborating on the syntax?

Comment: -e is the program to execute; -p tells perl that it should be wrapped with a loop processing all input files, executing the code for each line and then printing the line.  `s!!!g` is a substitution using ! as the delimiter; the g makes it run as many times as possible on each line.

Comment: in the regex, " matches literal quote characters, () is the part to capture and make available as `$1` in the replacement side, `[^"]` is a negated character class, matching any character but ", the `*` tells it to match the character class as many times as possible.

Comment: Here is my full string with ansi colors:
    perl -wpe's!"([^"]+)"!"\033[32m$1\033[0m!g'

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to put the colour tags as in your question or use ANSI colour in the terminal?  If it is the first, jkshah gave you an answer.  But if you want ANSI colour, it is a bit more tricky.  Try something like this:

```
sed -e $'s/"\([^"]\+\)"/"\033[1;34m\\1\033[0m"/g' <(echo 'foo "bar" baz')
```

Replace the `<(echo 'foo "bar" baz')` with the file you want to parse.

Comment: Correct, I just figured I would figure out the ANSI code after I figured out this. In your example, the entire file is returned unchanged.

Comment: Maybe then the ANSI escape sequence I used does not work on OS X.  I'm on Linux. What is your `$TERM` variable?

Comment: my $TERM is set to xterm

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid I don't know. I tested on my system, and works just fine.  I'm not familiar with OS X to suggest anything useful.  Although a quick search tells me other people face problems with colour on Mac terminals too.  Maybe that helps.